# What are Safe Allowances for Drilling into Rafters?

Tags: roof, truss

I plan to drill a hole for a screw into one of my (oversized) rafters near its bottom end where it meets the wall, into the narrow face pointing in towards the house. It will hold a negligible amount of weight but will mostly have transverse forces applied to it via pulleys.

Is there a basic formula or standard to determine how wide the screw can be and how deep it is allowed to penetrate the wood to not compromise the integrity of the rafter?

In my case I have pine rafters that are 3 3/8" x 9". They each have a collar tie but no ceiling joists as there is no 2nd floor. They are about 12' long.

Comment: The codified rules that I know of all involve drilling large holes (3/4" or so) for wiring and pipes to run through.  Those rules are pretty specific as to what is safe or not, but I don't think they concern themselves with something as small as a screw or lag hole.